# If $T : X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear bounded and 1-1 operator, with $T(B_X)=B_Y$ prove that $T$ is an isometry.

Tags: functional-analysis

My attempt: I showed that T is bijective: Let $0\neq y\in{Y}$ and $y_{0}=\frac{y}{||y||}$. Then, $y_{0}\in{B_{Y}}$ and therefore there exists $x\in{B_{X}}$ such that $Tx=y_{0}\implies T(||y||x)=y$. Furthermore, I proved that $||Tx||\leq ||x||$ for all $x\in{X}$ (1) and that $||T||=1$. For (1) we consider $0\neq x\in{X}$ and $x_{0}=\frac{x}{||x||}\in{B_X}$. Then, $T_{x_{0}}\in{B_Y}$ and thus $||T_{x_{0}}||\leq 1\implies ||T_x||\leq ||x||$ for all $x\neq 0$ and hence for all $x\in{X}$ since $T(0)=0$. But I don't know how to proceed to show that $||Tx||\ge ||x||$ for all x. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by “$B_X$”?

Comment: $B_{X}= \{x\in{X} : ||x||\leq 1 \}$, sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \neq 0$. Consider $\frac {Tx} {\|Tx\|}$.  (Note that $Tx\neq 0$ since $T$ is injective). Since $\frac {Tx} {\|Tx\|} \in B_Y$ we can write $\frac {Tx} {\|Tx\|}=Ty$ for some $y \in B_X$. Now $T(\frac {x} {\|Tx\|})=Ty$ so $\frac {x} {\|Tx\|}=y$. This gives $x=\|Tx\|y$ so $\|x\| \leq \|Tx\|$.

Answer (score 1):

The  assumption $T(B_X)=B_Y$ implies $\|T\|\le 1$ and $T(X)=Y$ (by homogeneity). As $T$ is injective $T^{-1}(B_Y)=B_X.$ Thus $\|T^{-1}\|\le 1.$ Hence
$$\|x\|=\|T^{-1}Tx\|\le \|Tx\|\le \|x\|$$ so $\|Tx\|=\|x\|.$